# How to change character string into yearqtr

Tags: r

I have a dataseries which looks like:

```
gdp <- structure(c(4.61992172242418, 4.6566625355851, 4.36946546173971, 
4.84162425714203, 5.27383573389955, 5.13243064162054, 4.95781801538584, 
5.26294884122223, 12.5001588735103, 14.5451731219964, 10.3624546107312, 
10.3243661354426), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("in.gdp.fc", 
"in.gdp.real", "in.gdpnagri")), index = c("Apr-Jun 2012", 
"Jul-Sep 2012", "Oct-Dec 2012", "Jan-Mar 2013"), class = "zoo")`
```

How can I change the index into 'yearqtr' class? I tried doing as.Date and then as.character.
It is throwing up some error saying: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Remove everything up to and including the minus and then use `as.yearqtr` with the appropriate [percent codes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

```
library(zoo)
gdp.yq <- gdp
index(gdp.yq) <- as.yearqtr(sub(".*-", "", index(gdp)), "%b %Y")
```

**2)** This also works and is a shorter:

```
library(zoo)
gdp.yq <- gdp
index(gdp.yq) <- as.yearqtr(index(gdp), "%b-%b %Y")
```